# Updating a row of SQL with html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE stat='Open'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close($con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
    <table class="striped">
            <tr class="header">
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Admin Name</td>
                <td>Category</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>Urgency</td>
                <td>Time In</td>
                <td> </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[username]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[title]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[description]."</td>";?>
           <td><select>
                <?php
                echo "<option value'".$row[admin_name]."'>".$row[admin_name]."</option>";
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE user_type='admin'");   
            while ($u = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<option value='".$u['username']."'>".$u['username']."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
           </select></td>
           <?php    
                   echo "<td>".$row[category]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[stat]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[urgency]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[time_in]."</td>";
                   echo "<td><a href='close.php'>Close Ticket</a></td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }
            ?>
        </table>
        <a href='update.php'>Update</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two links on this page.  Both of them need to update a SQL database.  The Close ticket link needs to just update the single row, while the update link should update all of them.  I am not sure how to get the info from one php to the next.  It seems like you can put the individual row information into a Post array for the close ticket link, but I am not sure how.  For the update link it needs to take the value of the dropdown in the table and change the admin_name field to that value.

Comment: Please go through the below link and also refer related you will find the better solution and will help in future.  Thanx....   [CRUD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131718/common-crud-functions-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not sure this helps.  If it does do what I want to do I am not sure what it is saying then.  I can right the queries just fine.  I am trying to figure out how to tell which rows are being updated and with what data.

Comment: You can use either <form> elements or AJAX to send the data to your PHP handler pages. The handler would connect to the database, and then run it's update query. Whatever you choose, there are many questions similar to this one.

Comment: Are you able to use Javascript and jQuery? Or do you want to use only HTML and PHP?

Comment: I can use whatever language I want, although I don't think my server has jquery installed on it (relatively new to web development), and I am not really familiar with java script.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library so all you need to do to use it is `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`  [Go to here to learn more](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)